# DataGridBoolColumn in a DataGrid (not DataGridView).. how is this supposed to work

Tags: winforms

I'm working on an old piece of WinForms based software which uses DataGrid and classes derived from things like DataGridtextBoxColumn.
I need to add a checkbox column, simple right? just create a similar class to the others which is derived from DataGridBoolColumn.. hmm but how do I use this control!?
I had really hoped to figure this out for myself but after a long time "testing" different techniques I'm no further really.  The issues are:

a) When not focused/editing the column, the checkbox is grey and checked (i've set allow null to false and TrueValue to true, FalseValue to false etc.

b) When editing the field I can check or uncheck the column, but when overridding the Commit method and then retrieving the value with GetColumnValueAtRow(source, rowNum) it's always false.. always, whether it's checked or not.

c) Finally when leaving the check box column after edit, it's back to being grey and checked regardless of what I did

Is it perhaps a data binding issue?  Doesn't appear to be.  It's simply my lack of WinForms experience and from what I can tell an old and not very intuitive MS API.

Does anyone have the relevant experience to point me in the right direction, as I'm totally loss as to best practice in this area?

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that WinForms is a black art to which few know the true nature..?

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. that was actually very simple.  You can say AllowNulls = false all you want, but if your DefaultValue is set to String.Empty, then it will always default to the "nulled" position (in terms of when it's painted at least).

Key things were:
col.DataType = typeof(bool);
col.DefaultValue = false;